# Unable to delete member pointer to array in destructor for class

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, delete-operator

So I am trying to delete my member pointer `m_memory` as it points to an array of `char`. When I try to delete the array that m_memory points to using `delete[]` I end up triggering breakpoints. I tried initializing `m_memory` as a `nullptr` before using `new` but it still triggered the breakpoint. Just wondering what my error is.

Header File:

```
#ifndef FISH_H
#define FISH_H
#include <iostream>
class Fish {
public:
    Fish(int capacity, std::string name);// Constructor
    Fish(const Fish &other); // Copy Constructor
    ~Fish(); // Destructor
    Fish &operator=(const Fish &other); // Assignment Operator
    void remember(char c); // Remember c
    void forget(); // Clears memory by filling in '.'
    void printMemory() const;// Prints memory
    std::string getName();
protected:
    const char* getMemory() const;// Returns memory
    int getAmount() const; // Returns amount remembered
    int getCapacity() const; // Returns memory capacity
private:
    std::string m_name;
    char * m_memory;
    int m_capacity;
    int m_remembered;
int m_replace;

};
#endif
```

Implementation file:

```
#include “fish.”

Fish::Fish(int capacity, std::string name) {// Constructor
    this->m_capacity = capacity;
    if (capacity > 0) {
        this->m_capacity = capacity;
    }
    else {
        this->m_capacity = 3;
    }

this->m_name = name;
this->m_memory = new char[this->m_capacity];
this->m_memory[this->m_capacity] = '\0';

for (int i = 0; i < this->m_capacity; i++) {
    this->m_memory[i] = '.';
    }
    this->m_remembered = 0;
    this->m_replace = 0;
}


Fish::~Fish() // Destructor
    {
        delete [] this->m_memory; //exception thrown, breakpoint triggered
    }
```

Main:

```
#include "fish.h"
int main() {
    Fish *nemo = new Fish(3, "nemo");
    nemo->~Fish();

}
```

Comment: I also wanted to mention that I tried deleting the pointer without prepending this-> to no avail.

Comment: Vaguely related:  You rarely want to call the destructor yourself, so `nemo->~Fish();` should be `delete nemo;`

Comment: Can we assume that there is a restriction in place preventing use of `std::string`?

Comment: I am aware of that but I will be using this class as a superclass so I will end up having to call the destructor in the derived class.

Comment: No. You won't have to call the destructor.  Make the destructor `virtual` and through the magic of polymorphism the correct destructors will be called regardless of whether operating on base classes or subclasses.

Comment: I don't get any compile errors due to using std::string the only issue I get is the breakpoints being caused by delete[].

Comment: Ok thanks. I was mainly just concerned what the issue is with my code and why it is causing breakpoints though. The syntax seems correct for deleting a pointer to an array. Maybe it is a scope issue?

Comment: Also I in my copy constructor I use delete [] this->m_memory so that I can dynamically allocate m_memory again so I can copy the contents of the other fish object I am copying from.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but all those repetitions of `this->m_` are incredibly distracting. Get rid of the noise.

Comment: My apologies. I didn't notice you were already using a `std::string`. I saw you making one the hard way with `m_memory` and jumped to a bad conclusion. The point stands, though, why not make `m_memory` a `std::string`? It would make thins much, much easier.

Comment: Show the code for the copy constructor. That's very likely to be where the problem is.

Comment: @Hikikomori The destructor for the derived class will automatically call the destructor for the base class. If you call it yourself it will be called twice and then stuff will go wrong.

Comment: I've updated my issue and found out why delete[] wasn't working properly, it was because I was adding a null terminator to my array manually which caused issues with deletion. Now my issue is that without adding the null termination character to my char array my array is storing extra data that I do not want it to.

Comment: My issue is coming from the constructor as when I set a breakpoint after initializing a Fish it stores what I posted above.

Comment: I was under the impression that when you initialize char arrays they store '\0' automatically as the null termination char.

Comment: I'm undoing the edit to the question because now it's a different question with different answers. If you have a different question (like "why does it show  ...ýýýý when I don't add a null terminating character?") then it needs to be asked as a different question.

Answer (score 4):

```
this->m_memory = new char[this->m_capacity];
this->m_memory[this->m_capacity] = '\0';
```

This writes outside the array. this->m_capacity is 3, so you're allocating 3 chars and then writing to the 4th one.

The computer isn't required to detect this problem. Microsoft is trying to be helpful here by detecting it, but their detection only happens when you free the memory. If you run your program in the debugger, you should see some messages in the Debug Output window explaining why your program crashed.

Comment: So I guess the solution would be to make m_capacity = capacity + 1 so I can explicitly add the "/0" terminating character. I like to add the null termination character myself because I've had problems in the past of my arrays having more than what I allocated in it and that seemed to solve the problem.

Comment: Would that solution prevent the breakpoint and or is adding the null terminating character causing the breakpoint and preventing me from using delete [] properly?

Comment: @Hikikomori Your second comment tells me I don't think you understood the problem.

Comment: Putting a null terminator in an array doesn't solve the problem of trying to put more in the array than is allocated.  That means you have other bugs elsewhere in your code. You likely aren't taking the array's capacity into account when filling the array, or when copying/printing the array.

Comment: The bad code is in the constructor, removing the null terminating character ended up letting me delete [] m_memory but ended up having appended garbage to the m_memory array when i looked at it in the local window on debug mode.

Comment: Now I'm trying to figure out how to keep the array from storing the extra garbage.

Comment: I've updated the question with relevant details if you are able to help.

Comment: @Hikikomori See, you still don't know what is going on. You *can* add the null terminator *and* have the delete[] work. Do you understand why the delete[] didn't work before though?

Comment: I've added the null terminator within bounds after resizing the array to accomodate an extra space for the null terminator. If I use a null terminator it ends up giving me the breakpoint issue even if the null terminator is within the amount of allocated memory/bounds of the array.

Comment: Well, I can't see your code so I don't know what to tell you besides "you did something wrong".

Comment: I constructed m_memory as this->m_memory= new char[m_capacity + 1] then after running a for loop initializing values with the condition i < m_capacity I assigned this->m_memory[m_capacity] = '\0' and now this is causing issues with delete [] m_memory.

Comment: In this case '\0' would have been assigned within the array allocation and bounds and makes the pointer m_memory point to "..." instead of "...yyyy" but now causes issues with using delete [] m_memory.

Comment: My main larger question is what I am doing wrong when using the null terminator that causes delete [] not to function properly.

Comment: I will note that if I initialize the pointer as a null pointer the construction without null termination results in "...(different garbage here of different length)".

Comment: @Hikikomori "My main larger question is what I am doing wrong when using the null terminator that causes delete [] not to function properly." - writing it outside the array, like I said.

Comment: As I said in the above comments though when I make room for the null terminator by making m_memory = new char[m_capacity + 1] and set m_memory[m_capacity] = '\0' the delete [] operator is still not working properly. When I leave out the null terminator whether I leave room for it or not delete [] functions properly.

Comment: Also I initialize values in the for loop while i < m_capacity so I wouldn't be adding any values out of bounds with those changes to the code yet I still get the same result.

Comment: In that case the problem must be something else. I made that change and ran your code (on Linux though, with Valgrind to catch errors) and didn't see any problems.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured out that the destructor was actually working fine it was the assignment operator that was running into problems when trying to use delete[]. Pretty much I want to delete[] m_memory and then resize it to accommodate a new char[copied.capacity] into m_memory. For some reason when I call delete[]  m_memory in the assignment operator it throws a breakpoint due to heap corruption. It may be the way I declared the function though in the header file and in the implementation file as that is the only thing I can think of that would cause delete[] to cause the error.

Comment: Fish &operator=(const Fish &other); // Assignment Operator in header file

Comment: Fish &Fish::operator=(const Fish &other) { delete[] m_memory;} //breakpoint thrown in implementation file

Comment: The code in this question doesn't use the assignment operator. If you have a question about different code, that's a different question too.